# Generate objects from data frame and multiply by given columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm facing a DataFrame of this shape:

```
   c1 c2 c3 c4 ....
0
1
2
.
.
.
```

Given a preset array of column names, say: `['c1','c2']` I want to create the following objects:

Per row, per preset column name:

```
{index:0, column: c1, extra: {c3: ... ,c4: ...}}
{index:0, column: c2, extra: {c3: ... ,c4: ...}}

{index:1, column: c1, extra: {c3: ... ,c4: ...}}
{index:1, column: c2, extra: {c3: ... ,c4: ...}}

{index:2, column: c1, extra: {c3: ... ,c4: ...}}
{index:3, column: c2, extra: {c3: ... ,c4: ...}}
```

What I tried and succeeded doing is a normal loop over the DataFrame, but from my understanding of previous work with DataFrames there should be an easier more "natural" way to achieve it.

I was trying to look at the function `to_dict` but was not able to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
print (df)
  c1 c2 c3 c4
0  a  s  d  f
1  q  w  e  r
2  m  n  j  h

#input list
cols = ['c1','c2']
#all columns without input
extra = df.columns.difference(cols)
#convert columns to dictionaries
df['extra'] = df[extra].apply(dict, 1)
#unpivot

df  = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars=['index', 'extra'], 
                            value_vars=cols, 
                            var_name='column').sort_values('index')
print (df)
   index                   extra column value
0      0  {'c3': 'd', 'c4': 'f'}     c1     a
3      0  {'c3': 'd', 'c4': 'f'}     c2     s
1      1  {'c3': 'e', 'c4': 'r'}     c1     q
4      1  {'c3': 'e', 'c4': 'r'}     c2     w
2      2  {'c3': 'j', 'c4': 'h'}     c1     m
5      2  {'c3': 'j', 'c4': 'h'}     c2     n
```

---

```
#convert to dict 
d = df[['index','column','extra']].to_dict(orient='records')
print (d)
[{'index': 0, 'column': 'c1', 'extra': {'c3': 'd', 'c4': 'f'}},
 {'index': 0, 'column': 'c2', 'extra': {'c3': 'd', 'c4': 'f'}},
 {'index': 1, 'column': 'c1', 'extra': {'c3': 'e', 'c4': 'r'}}, 
 {'index': 1, 'column': 'c2', 'extra': {'c3': 'e', 'c4': 'r'}}, 
 {'index': 2, 'column': 'c1', 'extra': {'c3': 'j', 'c4': 'h'}}, 
 {'index': 2, 'column': 'c2', 'extra': {'c3': 'j', 'c4': 'h'}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems way too specific to be implemented directly by pandas (if that is what you mean by "natural").

With that said, the closest thing I know of that might help you is :

```
Dataframe.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,1,2], 'b': [4,5,6]})

df.to_dict(orient='records')
# [{'a': 0, 'b': 4}, {'a': 1, 'b': 5}, {'a': 2, 'b': 6}]
```

From here you can extract to a new dict the index and the desired subset.